# jquery from google CDN is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn

I am trying to inject jquery CDN by javascript. The following code, however, does not seem to work giving me an error: "$ is not defined". Any help will be appreciated!

```
var jqry = document.createElement('script')
jqry.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js')
jqry.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
var jqui = document.createElement('script')
jqui.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js')
jqui.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript')
document.head.appendChild(jqry)
document.head.appendChild(jqui)

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert('no jquery')
}

$... // codes using jquery
```

Comment: Do you have access to the HTML? That would be a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scripts are being loaded asynchronously.

Listen `onload` event of the `script` element as `script` is not really loaded when `if-condition` is executed.

```js
var jqry = document.createElement('script')
jqry.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js')
jqry.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.head.appendChild(jqry)

jqry.onload = function() {
  if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    alert('no jquery')
  } else {
    alert('Loaded!');
    var jqui = document.createElement('script');
    jqui.setAttribute('src', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js')
    jqui.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.head.appendChild(jqui);
    jqui.onload = function() {
      alert('jquery-ui Loaded!');
    }
  }
}
```

A generalized function to load scripts asynchronously:

```js
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  script.onload = callback || function() {};
}
loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js', function() {
  alert('jQuery Loaded!');
  loadScript('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js')
})
```

Comment: Once jQuery is loaded, you would probably prefer to use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for loading the other script.

Comment: @4castle, Partially agree with you though this snippet is just to demonstrate how things work :) Thanks..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to write jquery codes inside jqry.onload function to make sure that the jquery is loaded?

Comment: @narusawa, Exactly!

Comment: @4castle that isn't nearly as efficient as creating a script element with native script and using native events

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src","https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

```html
<head></head>
```

OR

```js
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<head></head>
```